# win32com beating data validation

Tags: python, excel, win32com

I am using win32com to:

- open an instance of Excel,
- change some cell values, and
- save and close the instance of Excel.

Example:

```
xl = win32com.client.DispatchEx("Excel.Application")
wb = xl.Workbooks.Open(<enter file path here>)
ws = wb.Worksheets(<enter tab name here>)
ws.Range(<enter range name here>).Value = 2
wb.Close(True,<enter new file path here>)
```

My problem is that the relevant named range has a data validation which is being violated (in this instance `!= 2`), but no error message is produced. What I would like is for the Python process to be interrupted, or even shut down as a result of the data validation violation.

Comment: I doubt this is possible without recreating the data validation logic in your code.

Comment: Before closing the workbook, try reading the cell where the error would be displayed.

Comment: @MarkRansom Do you mean just something like "x = ws.Range(<enter range name here>).Value" after having set the range value to 2?

Comment: That would be a start, but I don't know what cell you're looking at to determine that you have an error.

Comment: That wouldn't work because data validation displays a program error message to the user, not an error message in the cell.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the [Validation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.validation) object of the Range to test the value:

Let's say cell B2 has a Validation rule that the value is not equal to 2, as in the OP's question.

```
import win32com.client as wc
    
def AssertValidValue(rng,newVal,throw = True):
    oldVal = rng.Value
    rng.Value = newVal

    validation = rng.Validation

    if not validation.Value:
        rng.Value = oldVal
        if throw:
            raise ValueError('{0:} is not a valid value for cell {1:}'.format(newVal,rng.Address))
        return False

    return True
        

xl = wc.Dispatch('Excel.Application')
wb = xl.Workbooks.Open('somepath\\Book1.xlsx')
ws = wb.Worksheets('Sheet1')
rng = ws.Range('B2')

try:
    AssertValidValue(rng,3)
    AssertValidValue(rng,2)
except ValueError as ve:
    print(ve)
```

Output:

```
2 is not a valid value for cell $B$2
```

and Cell B2 contains the value 3.